# Empty div with aspect ratio does not appear if parent is a flex element

Tags: css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

Please check out the snippet below: why do I see the first empty div with the correct aspect ratio, but not the same box wrapped in a flex element? And what can I do to see in the second case as well?

```css
.box {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9; 
  background: yellow;
  border: 5px solid red; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is not because of aspect-ratio, but "display : flex". You can view it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68739963/why-is-aspect-ratio-css-property-inside-flexbox-sometimes-ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial setting of a flex item is `flex-grow: 0`.

That's what you're seeing for the box element in the flex container.

```
no growth + no content = no width
```

Just add `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1` to give the item full width.

```css
.box {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9; 
  background: yellow;
  border: 5px solid red; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-grow: 1; /* NEW */
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow